# Using *ngFor to loop over data fetched from server

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, dynamic-list

I am very new to Angular.

I am fetching the list of posts on the server using the following code:

```
loadPosts():boolean{
if (!LoginService.authenticated){
  console.log('not auth');
  return false;
}
// fetch posts.
console.log('load');
PostService.fetchPosts(
  (response: Response) => {
    HomeComponent.allPosts = response;
    console.log("POSTS");
    console.log(HomeComponent.allPosts);
});
```

The `PostService.fetchPosts` returns the response which I then populate into the `allPosts` variable.

However, in the view:

```
<div *ngIf="!authenticated(); else elseBlock">
 Please log in first.
</div>

<ng-template #elseBlock>
    <div *ngFor="let post of allPosts">
      {{ post.heading }}
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

My list is not being updated.

home.component.ts file:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  static allPosts;

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private loginService: LoginService, private http: HttpClient, private postService: PostService) {
    this.loginService.authenticate(undefined, undefined, undefined);
    // setInterval(() => { console.log('checking'); this.ref.detectChanges}, 500 );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginService.authenticate(undefined, this.loadPosts, undefined);
  }

  authenticated(){
    return LoginService.authenticated;
  }

  add(){
    HomeComponent.allPosts = [{heading:'okay'}];
  }

  loadPosts():boolean{
    if (!LoginService.authenticated){
      console.log('not auth');
      return false;
    }
    // fetch posts.
    console.log('load');
    PostService.fetchPosts(
      (response: Response) => {
        HomeComponent.allPosts = response.json();
        console.log("POSTS");
        console.log(HomeComponent.allPosts);
    });
  }
}
```

post.service.ts:

```
export class PostService {

  static getPostUrl = 'http://localhost:8009/user/getposts';
  static http;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { PostService.http = http }

  static fetchPosts(successCallback, errorCallback?){
    this.http.get(this.getPostUrl, { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(
      (response: Response) => {
        successCallback(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        errorCallback? errorCallback(error) : {};
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: share the output of `console.log(response)` else verify the output of  function which returns the posts

Comment: [{…}]0: body: "WORLD!"heading: "HELLO"id: "5b5ef76091c3881da82e62e1"timestamp: "2018-07-30T11:32:48.256+0000"userEmailId: "user"

Comment: Add response.json()

PostService.fetchPosts(
  (response: Response) => {
    HomeComponent.allPosts = response.json();
    console.log("POSTS");
    console.log(HomeComponent.allPosts);
});

Comment: Share home.component.ts file code.

Comment: authenticated is a variable or a function? i think you might wrote the '()' by accident?

Comment: @Vinayak `TypeError: response.json is not a function` ...

Comment: @MukeshKumar Edited the question.

Comment: @DebanikDawn, you can not access static field in html file. Remove static modifier with allPosts field

Comment: Okay, removing the static worked, but if I don't make it static I cannot use the method `loadPosts()` as callback when the `HTTP GET` request returns values from the server. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access static field in the component's HTML file. Remove static modifier with allPosts field and replace **HomeComponent.allPosts** with **this.allPosts** in home.component.ts file

Comment: Okay, removing the static worked, but if I don't make it static I cannot use the method loadPosts() as callback when the HTTP GET request returns values from the server. How do I do that?

Comment: Done, Please check.

Comment: P.S: I'm hoping making utility methods like the one in the post.service.ts `static` is okay?

Comment: No. Please remove static from PostService too. I don't know why you are marking service method as static?

Comment: Why you are passing loadPosts to loginService.authenticate method?

Comment: I felt that that would be logical. It's an utility method. Makes a request to load data from the server.
Nevertheless, how do I make a callback (or any other solution to that)?

Comment: Because I wanted to load the posts on the home page as soon as I find that the user is authenticated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177171/discussion-between-mukesh-kumar-and-debanik-dawn).